# Files Are Not Being Copied After Grep Finds Files

Tags: string, grep

I have a script that searches for a string range. I want it to then take the files(s) it finds and copy them to a new location.

It seems to find the files but doesn't copy them. I am not sure what I have incorrect in my syntax.

```
find files/test/ -type f -exec grep -m1 2021{245..274} {} \; -exec cp -t files/new_location {} +
```

Here is the output from the above command:

```
grep: 2021246: No such file or directory
truncated.......
grep: 2021274: No such file or directory

files/test/sample1.txt.txt:P7AD PROCESSING DATE IS IN COLUMNS 81-87                                       2021245

grep: 2021246: No such file or directory
truncated.......
grep: 2021274: No such file or directory

files/test/sample2.txt:P7AD PROCESSING DATE IS IN COLUMNS 81-87                                        2021245

grep: 2021246: No such file or directory
truncated
grep: 2021274: No such file or directory

files/test/sample.txt:P7AD PROCESSING DATE IS IN COLUMNS 81-87                                        2021245

grep: 2021246: No such file or directory
truncated.......
grep: 2021274: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` doesn't understand ranges, so you need to express your range as an alternation.

I am not at a computer to test, but you need something like:

```
pattern="(2021)+($(echo {245..274} | tr ' ' '|'))+"
```

which should look like:

```
(2021)+(245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255|256|257|258|259|260|261|262|263|264|265|266|267|268|269|270|271|272|273|274)+
```

Then you can do:

```
grep -m1 -P "$pattern" ...
```

---

Or you should be able to create a file with all your patterns, one per line like this:

```
printf "2021%d\n" {245..274}
2021245
2021246
2021247
2021248
2021249
2021250
2021251
...
...
```

Then you can `grep` using that file as patterns with:

```
grep -f THATFILE FileToSearchIn.txt
```

And you can express that in `bash` without creating a file using a *"process substitution"* like this:

```
grep -f <(printf "2021%d\n" {245..274}) FileToSearchIn.txt
```